# Find pipelines that run an API

Tags: pipelines, experience-profile

Is there a simple way to determine what pipelines run for an API call? I am trying to extend the search in experience profile (Add columns) but can't find the pipelines so that I can add fields to the data table. I have already done the core DB work, but I need data in the API.

http://site/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount%20desc&match=level

### Update 1

The initialize routes for this API call is in Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("cintel_contact_search", "sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search", (object) new
{
     controller = "Contact",
     action = "Search"
});
```

[image]

Comment: A majority of the api calls do not actually have an associated pipeline. I have had to completely decompile the api used in SearchDataSource components and build my own to extend functionality.

Comment: That being said, if an API call does indeed have a pipeline, a simple decompile should reveal which pipeline fairly quickly.

Comment: I did find the pipeline for the Experience profile "<latest-visitors>" and extended that. But the search is being trouble.

Comment: this is just a normal controller action, you can override that by inheriting / using services from that controller

Comment: @AndreyBobrov if I create another initialize pipeline that create that same MapHttpRoute route with my controller details, will mine override the one that was created before me? I'll make sure my config is last in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Immediate Answer

You asked: "Is there a simple way to determine what pipelines run for an API call?"

In a nutshell, the only way to know for sure what an API controller is doing is to **decompile** the controller and take a peek. So, if that's not considered "simple", then the answer to your question is probably ***no***.

That being said, I'd like to offer up some information specifically on the Contact Search functionality that you are asking about, and provide you with a path for adding to the results that you are wanting to extend.

I'll start with an explanation of how Contact Search works. I will also add that a lot of the API controllers have similar methodologies.

### Understanding how Contact Search Works

The ***Contact API Controller***, when **Search()** is executed, performs a `Find(parameters)` method of the configured `ContactSearchProvider`.

This is defined in the **Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.config** as such:

```
  <providers>
    
    <!-- Provides contact search functionality. -->
    <contactSearchProvider type="Sitecore.Cintel.ContactSearchProvider, Sitecore.Cintel" singleInstance="true" />
     
  </providers>
```

The **ContactSearchProvider** provides the brains behind how the search is performed and returns a `ResultSet` list of results based off of the interface `IContactSearchResult`.

Once the Search is complete, the Contact Controller then passes the results off of to a Result Transformer, that takes the results and converts them into a JSON response that is then passed through the API controller and back to the client browser.

The Result Transformer that is used in the Experience Profile is called `ContactSearchResultTransformer` and is defined in the config file **Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.Client.config**

```
      <contactSearchResultTransformer>
        <add key="default" type="Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.Contact.ContactSearchResultTransformer, Sitecore.Cintel.Client" />
      </contactSearchResultTransformer>
```

A look at the out of the box result transformer reveals an example on how to ***extend*** the JSON results.

```
public object Transform(ResultSet<List<IContactSearchResult>> resultSet)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) resultSet, "resultSet");
  if (resultSet.Data.Dataset.Count == 0)
    return (object) resultSet;
  List<IContactSearchResult> source = resultSet.Data.Dataset.FirstOrDefault<KeyValuePair<string, List<IContactSearchResult>>>().Value;
  if (source == null)
    return (object) resultSet;
  DateTime nowTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  List<ContactSearchResultEx> list = source.Select<IContactSearchResult, ContactSearchResultEx>((Func<IContactSearchResult, ContactSearchResultEx>) (r => this.ExtendResult(r, nowTime))).ToList<ContactSearchResultEx>();
  source.Clear();
  source.AddRange((IEnumerable<IContactSearchResult>) list);
  return (object) resultSet;
}

private ContactSearchResultEx ExtendResult(IContactSearchResult result, DateTime nowTime)
{
  ContactSearchResultEx contactSearchResultEx = new ContactSearchResultEx(result);
  contactSearchResultEx.FormattedLatestVisitStartDateTime = this.timeConverter.FormatDateTime(result.LatestVisitStartDateTime);
  contactSearchResultEx.Recency = this.timeConverter.GetRecency(result.LatestVisitStartDateTime, nowTime);
  contactSearchResultEx.LatestVisitLocationDisplayName = this.textConverter.GetLocation(result.LatestVisitLocationCityDisplayName, result.LatestVisitLocationRegionDisplayName, result.LatestVisitLocationCountryDisplayName);
  contactSearchResultEx.EmailAddressExt = this.textConverter.GetEmail((object) result.PreferredEmail);
  string duration = this.timeConverter.GetDuration(result.LatestVisitStartDateTime, result.LatestVisitEndDateTime);
  contactSearchResultEx.LatestDuration = duration;
  string[] strArray = new string[3]
  {
    result.FirstName,
    result.MiddleName,
    result.Surname
  };
  string fullName = this.textConverter.GetFullName((ContactIdentificationLevel) result.IdentificationLevel, strArray);
  contactSearchResultEx.FullName = fullName;
  return contactSearchResultEx;
}
```

The magic here is that Transform() returns an `object` and not a concrete class.

Notice the method `ExtendResult()` returns a `ContactSearchResultEx` object. A look at this class shows that it is adding 6 different, additional JSON values to the search result.

```
[JsonProperty("formattedLatestVisitStartDateTime")]
public string FormattedLatestVisitStartDateTime { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("recency")]
public string Recency { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("latestVisitLocationDisplayName")]
public string LatestVisitLocationDisplayName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("emailAddressExt")]
public string EmailAddressExt { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("fullName")]
public string FullName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("latestDuration")]
public string LatestDuration { get; set; }
```

### Extending the Contact Search Results Further

With a basic understanding of how the Contact Search works currently, to add additional fields, I would do the following:

1. Start with creating a new *ContactSearchResultExtended* class that inherits from `ContactSearchResultEx`, adding the appropriate JSON properties to represent the new data that you want to return.
2. Create a custom `ContactSearchResultTransformer` class that mimics the same functionality as the out of the box class, but adds in whatever logic is needed in order to add the additional data to the result set in your own *ExtendResult* method.  Keep in mind that you pass in the *result* which contains **Contact ID** so that if you need to perform operations on the Contact ID in this method, you can. I would also preserve whatever logic is needed to satisfy the original extended results as well.
3. Create the appropriate patch configs to apply the config changes needed to utilize the new custom `<contactSearchResultTransformer>`.

### A Pipeline Approach (Theoretically)

Sadly, as shown here, there's really not a pipeline utilized to adjust, extend, or affect the result list. It's all in the configured Result Transformer.  However, I love looking at unpipelined logic and seeing where I might be able to apply a pipeline.

In this case, the `Transform()` method of the Result Transformer seems like a potential candidate for adding a pipline. Specifically, I can see a pipeline process that allows for the addition of additional JSON values as part of the embedded function:

```
List<ContactSearchResultEx> list = source.Select<IContactSearchResult, ContactSearchResultEx>((Func<IContactSearchResult, ContactSearchResultEx>) (r => this.ExtendResult(r, nowTime))).ToList<ContactSearchResultEx>();
```

Then each processor would be responsible for adding values to the result. Obviously, I haven't actually tried this, nor do I think it's actually needed since you can easily just create your own transform results.

However... it's a possible thought.

Comment: As always Pete very well thought out answer. Let me try some of this out. I might need to make a new ContactSerchProvider. I need to add a new custom field to search on. So I'll need a new IndexedContact and a new QueryIndex to add my fields. IQueryable<IndexedContact> source = queryable.Where<IndexedContact>((Expression<Func<IndexedContact, bool>>) (q => q.FullName.MatchWildcard<string>(wildcard) || q.Emails.MatchWildcard<List<string>>(wildcard)));

Comment: Yeah, if you need to affect the way the search is actually performed, then it is reasonable to think you'll want your own search provider.  That's also why I included this as part of the answer, so that you can see the provider is actually configurable and customizable. Happy Coding!